# erorr when react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

when react-native run-android erorr

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
>
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 1):

`react-native run-android` is basically running `./gradlew installDebug`. And the error says it all. There is `no connected devices` so it is not able to install the app.

Answer (score 1):

There are not connected Android devices or emulators running.

If you are using an Android Emulator, make sure that your emulator is up and running. If you are running on a real device, make sure that the Developer Mode is enabled on your device and USB Debugging is enabled.

Run `adb devices` to see the list of currently connected Android instances.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answering the question very soon.
The simulator was not run
The problem was solved

Comment: Please pick an answer as an "accepted answer" so this question can be marked as "answered". Thanks.